# Generate Even Amount of Runs in Left and Right Lanes for Racers

Tags: excel, random, vba

I'm working on a spreadsheet for a soap box derby type race that can automatically generate an even amount of runs in the left and right line per racer. It also will randomize who races against who. Currently, I have 6 heats and a button above each one. It pulls from a list of racers with a randomly generated number in the cell next to it using the method shown here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4591-excel-random-selection-no-duplicates.html

This is what the sheet looks like.
[![img][1]][1]
 The 'DON'T TOUCH' column is then copied to another sheet and placed in each heat when a button is pressed above that heat. The heat sheet looks like this: ![img][2]

Each time a heat button is clicked, it will copy and paste from the "Randomizer" sheet and since the sheet refreshes each time, it will be randomized on each button click. The following macro runs when a heat button is clicked.

```
Sub btnHeat1_Click()
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim xRg As Range
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  Dim Shp As Shape
  Set xRg = Application.Selection
  Set WS = ActiveSheet
  Set Shp = WS.Shapes("btnHeat1")
  Worksheets("Randomizer").Range("E4:E62").Copy
  Worksheets("The Race is On").Range("F4:F62").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  xRg.Select
  Shp.Visible = False
End Sub
```

I need to improve the randomizer so that each racer has an even amount of runs in the left and right lane (3 times each side). I'm not sure how to go about doing this and couldn't find any examples online of a similar situation (drag race heats, golf outings, etc). I thought of recording right and left lane each time a heat button is clicked, but not sure how to implement that into the existing randomizer. Or all the heats need to be generated at once and right and left lanes can represent a 0 and 1 in the randomizer equation.

Any suggestion on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Edit: Removed images to protect names

Comment: Technically speaking, you're not seeking random results if you require them to be evenly distributed.  You could have a list (perhaps an array) of all required placements and pick from it randomly to determine the order, each iteration of the loop picking from only the "un-picked" items.

Comment: Racers would be randomly generated for each heat, but need to ensure they are even distributed. Being even is more important than 2 racers racing against each other multiple times since the winner is determined by time, not by knockout.

Comment: You have 16 racers; will this always be the case - or does the algorithm need to take into account a more dynamic approach to assignment?

Comment: Will need a dynamic approach as we're not sure how many racers there will be. There just so happens to be 16 on this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following code should work as the basis for what you are trying to achieve - please note this currently generates the heats in the activesheet with contestants assigned numerically; further work will be required to adapt to your worksheet

> it creates an array of contestants then sequentially 'shifts' the elements of the array a calculated amount so that over the full amount of heats each element should appear equally in the first half and the second half of each 'heat' array. The array is then split in half and each half is randomised.
>
> Therefore it should generate a random pairing where each contestant is equally in the right or left lane as the problem stated...

```
Sub GenerateHeatData()
    Dim Contestants As Long: Contestants = 16
    Dim Heats As Long: Heats = 6
    Dim CycleLength As Long: CycleLength = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Contestants / Heats, 1)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Arr() As Variant, Left() As Variant, Right() As Variant

    Dim BaseArray() As Variant
    ReDim BaseArray(Contestants - 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(BaseArray)
        BaseArray(i) = i + 1
    Next i

    Dim BaseHeatArray() As Variant
    ReDim BaseHeatArray(Heats - 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(BaseHeatArray)
        BaseHeatArray(i) = i + 1
    Next i

    Call RandomiseArray(BaseHeatArray)

    For i = 0 To Heats - 1
        Arr = RightShiftArray(BaseArray, CycleLength * CLng(BaseHeatArray(i)))
        Left = ExtractArray(Arr, 0, WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(UBound(Arr) / 2, 1))
        Right = ExtractArray(Arr, UBound(Left) + 1, UBound(Arr) - UBound(Left))
        Call RandomiseArray(Left)
        Call RandomiseArray(Right)
        For j = 0 To UBound(Left)
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j + 1, 3 * i + 1) = CLng(Left(j))
        Next j
        For j = 0 To UBound(Right)
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j + 1, 3 * i + 2) = CLng(Right(j))
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Function RightShiftArray(InArray() As Variant, Shift As Long) As Variant()
    Shift = Shift Mod (UBound(InArray) + 1)
    If Shift < 1 Then Shift = Shift + UBound(InArray)

    Dim TempArr() As Variant: ReDim TempArr(Shift - 1)
    Dim i As Long, Arr() As Variant

    ReDim Arr(LBound(InArray) To UBound(InArray))
    For i = LBound(InArray) To UBound(InArray)
        Arr(i) = InArray(i)
    Next i

    For i = 0 To UBound(TempArr)
        TempArr(i) = Arr(UBound(Arr) - Shift + i + 1)
    Next i
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr) - Shift
        Arr(UBound(Arr) - i) = Arr(UBound(Arr) - i - Shift)
    Next i
    For i = 0 To UBound(TempArr)
        Arr(i) = TempArr(i)
    Next i

    RightShiftArray = Arr
End Function

Function RandomiseArray(Arr() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Temp As Variant

    Randomize
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        j = CLng(((UBound(Arr) - i) * Rnd) + i)
        If i <> j Then
            Temp = Arr(i)
            Arr(i) = Arr(j)
            Arr(j) = Temp
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Function ExtractArray(InArray() As Variant, First As Long, Length As Long) As Variant()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim i As Long, Arr() As Variant
    ReDim Arr(Length - 1)
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Arr(i) = InArray(First + i)
    Next i
    ExtractArray = Arr
End Function
```

*** EDIT - Add mirror assignments ***

```
Sub GenerateHeatData()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, Left() As Variant, Right() As Variant

    Dim Contestants As Long: Contestants = 10
    Dim Heats As Long: Heats = 6 ' Heats should be even
    Dim BaseArray() As Variant: ReDim BaseArray(Contestants - 1)
    For i = 0 To UBound(BaseArray)
        BaseArray(i) = i + 1
    Next i

    For i = 0 To Heats / 2 - 1
        Call RandomiseArray(BaseArray)
        Left = ExtractArray(BaseArray, 0, WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(UBound(BaseArray) / 2, 1))
        Right = ExtractArray(BaseArray, UBound(Left) + 1, UBound(BaseArray) - UBound(Left))

        Call RandomiseArray(Left)
        For j = 0 To UBound(Left)
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j + 1, 3 * i + 1) = CLng(Left(j))
        Next j
        Call RandomiseArray(Left)
        For j = 0 To UBound(Left)
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j + 1, 3 * (i + Heats / 2) + 2) = CLng(Left(j))
        Next j

        Call RandomiseArray(Right)
        For j = 0 To UBound(Right)
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j + 1, 3 * i + 2) = CLng(Right(j))
        Next j
        Call RandomiseArray(Right)
        For j = 0 To UBound(Right)
            ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(j + 1, 3 * (i + Heats / 2) + 1) = CLng(Right(j))
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Function RandomiseArray(Arr() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Temp As Variant

    Randomize
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        j = CLng(((UBound(Arr) - i) * Rnd) + i)
        If i <> j Then
            Temp = Arr(i)
            Arr(i) = Arr(j)
            Arr(j) = Temp
        End If
    Next i
End Function

Function ExtractArray(InArray() As Variant, First As Long, Length As Long) As Variant()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim i As Long, Arr() As Variant
    ReDim Arr(Length - 1)
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Arr(i) = InArray(First + i)
    Next i
    ExtractArray = Arr
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Decided instead of modifying the code for an array of names, I'll just associate each name to an "ID number" and populate the heats based on them. Thanks!

Comment: Going through your code at the moment, seems I still get some numbers that aren't equally left and right. Testing with 10 contestants.

Comment: OK - some issues with the ceiling function rounding means a few numbers don't get equal weighting; I've now altered the code so the 1st and 4th are mirror images etc then randomised; You'll generally need even contestants/heats to get a good result. hopefully this will prove better.

Comment: Thanks! Works great